# Look for repeated values inside row arrays of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was looking for this question but I didn't find something similar.

So, as an example I have a df like this:

```
         GROUP                         CATEGORY

          ONE          [pretty, intuitive, new, expensive, imported]
          TWO          [new, small, expensive,  useful]
         THREE         [innovative, small, expensive, pretty]
```

What I was trying to do is get a dataframe that shows every repeated value for each row, then I may know where these are located.

```
         GROUP              CATEGORY

          ONE       pretty, new, expensive
          TWO       new, small, expensive
         THREE      small, expensive, pretty
```

I've reading the documentation of the duplicated.() method, however since values are inside a np.array it returns an error, furthermore it just shows booleans and I'm not sure if that is the correct way to handle it because I have values that repeat more than twice.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: So you want to drop non-duplicates? Do you want them to stay in an array for the output (your example output, if that is what that is, doesn't have [])?

Comment: I feel like this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly is your goal here?

Comment: Yeah, well, it is don't a problem if the output has the [ ], basically is what you mention, drop the non-duplicates.

Comment: However, I found that handlind the [ ] while looking for the duplicates in a dataframe might represent a problem. Goal is to show repeated values for each row.

Comment: @fega_zero Does the order of values in `CATEGORY` column matters in the output? For example is `new, expensive, pretty` valid instead of `pretty, new, expensive`..

Comment: Not at all @Shubham Sharma, it doesn't.

Comment: @fega_zero Does each array in `CATEGORY` contains unique values?

Comment: An easy way to do this is probably just to use set() and intersection of the arrays. Then you will just have one array with the duplicate values. You'll lose the ordering of the different values within the different rows (all rows would be same order). Is that okay?

Comment: Yes @Shubham Sharma, I got this df from grouping two columns and applying the .unique() method.

Comment: @noah, yes, well from what I know, I'm pretty new using python,I could do the intersection between the arrays inside a for loop. Maybe you can do it better with your method.

Comment: Hey @fega_zero, just wanted to know if you have found any solution to the problem yet, as for your problem a vectoroized solution might not be possible..

Comment: Hi @Shubham Sharma , yeah, Tunahan A. did a good result. You can check it in the answers. Thanks for taking time to check the question, you´re right, since the arrays has unique values it can be solved as you mention.

Comment: @fega_zero That's great..Actually i was thinking of an idea before but not sure if its any more efficient :)

Comment: I'll be very glad if you share it!

Comment: @fega_zero Sure will do :-)

Comment: @fega_zero Added the alternative solution, not sure if thats what you required but you can try and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is this. My approach might be old school but it works.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'],
      'category': [["pretty", "intuitive", "new", "expensive", "imported"],
      ["new", "small", "expensive",  "useful"],
      ["innovative", "small", "expensive", "pretty"]]})

temp_list = []
for i in df['category']:
   temp_list.extend(i)

count_nested_list = pd.Series(temp_list)
count_nested_list = count_nested_list.value_counts()

nested_list = []
for i in range(len(count_nested_list)):
   if count_nested_list[i] == 1:
      nested_list.append(count_nested_list.index[i])
   else:
      pass

for i in nested_list:
   for j in range(len(df)):
      if i in df['category'][j]:
         df['category'][j].remove(i)
      else:
         pass
df

duplicates = count_nested_list[count_nested_list > 1]
duplicates
```

Comment: Hey,I understand most of your method, however at the last if statement an '==' is missing, furthermore may I ask you how to get the output after the end of the loop to show the duplicates?

Comment: Hey, I used "i in df['category'][j] instead of "==" operator because df['category'][j] is a list and I cannot check whether the element is in the list or not with "==". Therefore, I used "in" operator. I have updated the code so you can just copy+paste and run it on your script.

Comment: Answer to your second question, "duplicates = count_nested_list[count_nested_list > 1]" will show you which elements are duplicated and how many times.

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a function which identify the repeated values by counting the occurrences of values using `Series.value_counts`:

```
def repeated(s):
    cnt = pd.Series.value_counts(np.hstack(s))
    for a in s:
        c = pd.Series.value_counts(a)
        yield ', '.join(c[(cnt - c).ge(1)].index)

df['CATEGORY'] = list(repeated(df['CATEGORY']))
```

---

```
   GROUP                  CATEGORY
0    ONE    new, pretty, expensive
1    TWO     new, expensive, small
2  THREE  pretty, expensive, small
```